# Can I create a node group with a texture input

Tags: node-editor

Is it possible to create a node group that asks for a texture, along with other values?

Here is a similar example of materials instead:

[image]

Instead of a material, can I make it a texture input instead?

I assume you can only do this with python, and am not sure how to add it with python. Is it possible with just nodes in Blender v. 2.79?

Comment: What about a regular color socket, won't that work for you? It will accet input of any texture node.

Comment: I want to see how much I can compress the nodes, if at all, into one shader group.

Comment: Only by using python. In this case you need to have an internal image texture node in the nodetree, and access it through a your custom UI. Read more here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67487/cycles-materials-math-node-with-more-than-two-inputs/99003#99003