# procedural texture with varied coverage

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I want to generate textures with varied coverage, namely, the percentage of filled pixels varies.

From the coding perspective, we could achieve this using quad-tree, i.e., subdivide the image into nodes, and filling in nodes until reaching the required percentage.

The problem is how to achieve this in blender? I insist to use procedural texture instead of UV mapping because, the latter might not use up the whole image, thus the percentage of coverage would likely change.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is an image I got using quad-tree, it doesn't look natural, but the texture coverage is 50%, and that's the effect I want.

[image]

Comment: Could you add some illustrations/images to your question?

Comment: image added....

Comment: You're probably looking for [OSL nodes](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10972/28015)...

Comment: Can you elaborate on that, or some example that showcase this kind of effect.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you are expecting? I mean: if this is procedural there is no uv map, ok. But the quad-tree needs to be oriented along the mesh, so, what do you expect about that?

Comment: It doesn't have to be quad-tree. What I need to achieve is create a texture where a certain percentage of the texture are filled while the other area is uniform. The quad-tree is just a way to achieve this. It can totally be some other ways.