# Is it possible to use python in Cycles mode with the same power as in BGE?

Tags: python

Say I want to use Cycles mode, and I want to be able to use python code to, say, (make up), create heck a video game (I know BGE is better for this). Is it possible to use python code in Cycles mode to make this "game"? Or does Cycles mode limit python to shaders, or simply limits its power?

Comment: Short answer is *No.* You are mixing two different concepts, please read the *Performance* section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_tracing

Comment: The question is not about making a game or its performance. It's about the power of python. If python in Cycles mode can't do the same as in BGE mode, render performance doesn't even have to be discussed.

Comment: Two different things. BGE is a game engine like *Unreal Engine* built for **game creation** (player interaction). The Python API however, allows to extend blenders built-in functionality. It can be used to automate boring and especially complex tasks when it comes to **creating all kinds of 3d stuff** within the application itself. Better? Again, you can find all the different concepts at wikipedia or even the [blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/) thus I suggest read about that first, otherwise your questions pointless.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Better?" Better as in BGE is better or as in "better now"? Searching online brings up questions about "Cycles python for shaders" and never talks about using code for anything else. I get BGE is made for player interactivity/game development. But can I have python run a whole lot a things in Cycles mode or is python limited to only "calling" materials? It's seriously a simple question. Code code code, it runs wonders. But maybe not in Cycles mode, "as if you can't use python in Cycles mode".

Comment: My question was: Is that a *better* explanation? In other words: Do you understand the difference now? Regarding to your comment: You can [create nodes and connect them](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23436/31447) in order to generate a shader, but you can not *write python code to create the shader itself* (without creating nodes), unless you go with OSL to write your own shader within the [script node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10960/31447). Also there is no *cycles mode*, when pressing render, blender basically collects all the scene information and sends it to cycles...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Forget Cycles - make up Cycles is lightspeed fast. Now, focus on Python in Cycles (no BGE) - could I code a game? Why or why not? It's all about the code, not objects/render/real-time/physics.

Comment: No, because there is no way to create any player interaction. It's an *API* not an *Engine*, read about that. As mentioned before `It can be used to automate boring as well as complex tasks when it comes to creating all kinds of 3d content within the application itself.` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface