# OSL Script from External Source?

Tags: shaders

Sorry if this is a "duh" question, but I'd like to use a custom OSL shader, but I'd like it to be sourced from an objective location on my hard drive. How exactly would I go about this in the most efficient manner?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the Cycles 'Script' node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10960/understanding-the-cycles-script-node)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Remember, [close when finding duplicate questions, not when finding duplicate answers](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/549/599). Though, in this case I'm not even sure that answer has an answer to "how to use an OSL script from an external file"?

Comment: Well on the "*Using an OSL Shader*" section it does specify it can be used with an internal or external file, though to be fair it doesn't thoroughly go into details explaining it step by step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the *External* mode on the script node and set the filepath to your .osl source file or a compiled .oso file. Or, if you put your shaders under the shader search path (see below), you can simply specify the filename.

[image]

From [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/script.html):

> The External mode can be used to specify a .osl file from a drive, and
>   this will then be automatically compiled into a .oso file in the same
>   directory. It is also possible to specify a path to a .oso file, which
>   will then be used directly, with compilation done manually by the
>   user. The third option is to specify just the module name, which will
>   be looked up in the shader search path.
>
> The shader search path is located in the same place as the scripts or
>   configuration path, under:
>
> **Linux**
>
> ```
>  $HOME/.config/blender/2.79/shaders/
> ```
>
> **MS-Windows**
>
> ```
> C:\Users\$user\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\shaders\
> ```
>
> **macOS**
>
> ```
> /Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.79/shaders/
> ```